# SharePoint Online: Unable to create custom form - Could not save the list changes to the server

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, error, custom-form

I am not able to create custom form for any list across the whole tenant and getting the error:

> "Could not save the list changes to the server".

I am working in SharePoint online and using SP Designer 2013. I am the site collection administrator.

It was working before and stopped working a few days back. I have tried following things but the issue is yet not resolved:

1) Checked "Allow custom scripts" from admin center.

2) Add and customize pages permission is granted.

3) Cleared designer cache.

4) Checked using another site collection administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is current fixed, you can create custom form from SharePoint designer now.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e20d379-a650-44f9-8636-734d6379229b/sharepoint-list-custom-form-creation?forum=onlineservicessharepoint